# OpenLDAP using ipv6 link-local address "Can't contact LDAP Server (-1)"

Tags: ipv6, openldap

I'm trying to use IPV6 to connect to my LDAP server. Everything works if I use ipv4 but I'm not ipv6 link-local address. I used the following command on my server using its own ipv6 address. Any clue what I'm doing wrong? I can use ping6 to ping the server from client and client from server.

ldapsearch -D "user" -H "ldap://[fe80:20c:29ff:fefd:deea] -W returns Can't contact LDAP Server (-1)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IPv6 address is incomplete. You forgot the scope ID, which appears as a `%` followed by the relevant interface ID.

Comment: How do I find the scope ID? fe80:20c:29ff:fefd:deea/64 Scope:Link

Comment: As stated before, it's the interface.

Comment: I have tried this but it get the same reponse and I have tried with it in the brackets. ldapsearch -D "user" -H "ldap://[fe80:20c:29ff:fefd:deea]%eth0" -W

Comment: @Chris The % and interface name are part of the IPv6 address. So, they belong within the brackets, not outside them.

Comment: It doesn't work with -H option but -h worked. ldapsearch -D "user" -h fe80:20c:29ff:fefd:deea%eth0 -W. Not sure why. -h is for host and -H is for uri.